# "Error: expected identifier before '(' token" while accessing a structure

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to do the following:

```
struct LinkedListStruct
{
  void* this;
  LinkedList * next;
};


struct GraphLinkedList
{
    int V; 
    int E;
    LinkedList** adjlist; 
};






/*
 *  Function:
 *    getItemLinkedList
 *
 *  Description:
 *    Gets the item of a linked list node.
 *
 *  Arguments:
 *    Pointer to a linked list node:
 *        (LinkedList *) node
 *
 *  Return value:
 *    Returns the pointer to the item of a linked list node. NULL
 *   is returned if the node is NULL (or if the item is NULL).
 */
Item getItemLinkedList(LinkedList * node)
{
  /* Check if node is not empty                                   */
  if(node == NULL)
    return NULL;

  return node->this;
}



/*
 *  Function:
 *    insertUnsortedLinkedList
 *
 *  Description:
 *    Creates a new linked list node.
 *
 *  Arguments:
 *    Item to associate to the new node:
 *      Item this
 *    Pointer to the next node:
 *      (LinkedList *) next
 *
 *  Return value:
 *    Returns the pointer to the node.
 */
LinkedList * insertUnsortedLinkedList(LinkedList * next, Item this)
{
  LinkedList * new;

  /* Memory allocation                                            */
  new = (LinkedList *) malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

  /* Check memory allocation errors                               */
  if(new == NULL)
    return NULL;

  /* Initialize new node                                          */
  new->this = this;
  new->next = next;

  return new;
}




GraphLinked* GraphInit (int V, int E)
{
    GraphLinked* G=NULL;
    int i=0;
    int init[2]={-1,0};

    G= (GraphLinked*) calloc(1, sizeof(GraphLinked));

    G->V=V; 
    G->E=E;

    G->adjlist=(LinkedList**) calloc(V, sizeof(LinkedList*)); 

    for(i=0; i<V; i++)
    { 
        G->adjlist[i]=insertUnsortedLinkedList(NULL, (Item)init);
    }

    return G;
}


void EdgeAdd (GraphLinked* G, int edge[3])
{
    int info[2]={0}; 
    LinkedList* new=NULL;

    info[0]=edge[1]; 
    info[1]=edge[2];

    new=insertUnsortedLinkedList(G->adjlist[edge[0]]->next, (Item) info); 
    G->adjlist[edge[0]]=new;

    info[0]=edge[0];

    new=insertUnsortedLinkedList(G->adjlist[edge[1]]->next, (Item) info);
    G->adjlist[edge[1]]=new;
}


void ReadtoList (GraphLinked *G, FILE *input)
{
    int edge[3]={0}; 
    int i=0; 

    for(i=0; i<G->E; i++)
    {
        if(fscanf(input, "%d %d %d", &edge[0], &edge[1], &edge[2])!=3)
            exit(0);
        EdgeAdd(G, edge);
    }
}


void PrintList (GraphLinked *G, FILE *output)
{
    LinkedList *aux=NULL;
    int i=0;

    fprintf(output, "%d\n", G->V);

    for(i=0; i<G->V; i++)
    {
        aux=G->adjlist[i]; 
        while(aux!=NULL)
        {
            fprintf(output, "%d:%d\n", (int)(aux->((int*)this[0])), i);

            aux=aux->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The only relevant function is the last one. 
In this line:

```
fprintf(output, "%d:%d\n", (int)(aux->((int*)this[0])), (int)(aux->((int*)this[1])));
```

I get the error: "Error: expected identifier before '(' token" while accessing a structure"
It's probably some problem with the syntax that I'm not getting. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Your example is both not minimal and not complete (what is a `LinkedList`)?

Comment: Besides please show which character in the line of code the compiler is pointing to.

Comment: I'll add my header file. It's pointing to the parenthesis after the arrow.

Comment: You also want to explain what you're trying to do. Why do you cast `this` to `int*` and access element `0`? Then access a pointer member with that? _Obviously_ it's invalid code, but I don't understand your code, so I _can't_ fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fprintf(output, "%d:%d\n", (int)(aux->((int*)this[0])), (int)(aux->((int*)this[1])));
```

Probably you meant this:

```
fprintf(output, "%d:%d\n", ((int*)(aux->this))[0], ((int*)(aux->this))[1]);
```

You can't put anything between `->` and member name. The expression `aux->this` has the type `void *`. You want to cast `this` member to `int*` you do that like this: `(int*)aux->this`. If you know that `aux->this` points to array of integers and you want to get the value of the second element in that array, you do `((int*)aux->this)[1]`.

And for some reference: [member access operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access). `->` is a member access operator, it takes a `expression` (e.g. declared variable name) and a `member_name` (literally name, an [identifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier)). You can't put anything after `->` before `member_name`, `s->(int*)member_name` is invalid. The [cast operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast) has lower precedence than `->`, so the compiler will first execute `->` operator and then cast, that way: `(int*)(aux->this)` is the same as `(int*)aux->this`. Operators are evaluated left to right and operators with same precedence are grouped together, so in an expression `(int*)aux->this[1]` operators `->` and `[]` will be grouped together and evaluated left to right, so first will be evaluated `->`, than `[]`, than cast. So `(int*)aux->this[1]` is the same as `(int*)(aux->this[1])`, see [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). And you probably wanted to evaulate `[]` lastly, so we needed additional braces `((int*)aux->this)[1]`.